# Filter dataframe based on values from 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

| country | values |
| --- | --- |
| BG | 20 |
| BG | 4 |
| BG | 3 |
| BG | -3 |
| BG | -20 |
| DE | 20 |
| DE | 3 |
| DE | -20 |
| IND | 20 |
| IND | -2 |

I want to filter the dataframe in such a way that values from BG should be < absolute (5) and all other countries should be < 5 such that the dataframe becomes

| country | values |
| --- | --- |
| BG | 4 |
| BG | 3 |
| BG | -3 |
| DE | 3 |
| DE | -20 |
| IND | -2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
>>> df[(df["country"].eq("BG")&df["values"].abs().lt(5))|(df["country"].ne("BG")&df["values"].lt(5))]

  country  values
1      BG       4
2      BG       3
3      BG      -3
6      DE       3
7      DE     -20
9     IND      -2
```

Comment: My mistake, can you add a code when all other countries like DE and IND values should be <5

Comment: Yes, everything except BG should be <5

Comment: Thanks alot, how would you edit this code if there was another country GB which had to follow the same condition as BG